# How to make Jquery's .html() function in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking all over the web for how to do this. I am trying to make Jquerys .html() function in vanilla JavaScript. I want to recreate so I can understand it better. I've tried the following but nothing seems to work, I just don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
let $ = function(ele) {
    if (ele.charAt(0) == '.' || ele.charAt(0) == '#') {
    let newEle = cut(ele,0);
    if (ele.charAt(0) == '#')
        get(newEle);
    else
        return document.getElementsByClassName(newEle);
  } else
    return document.getElementById(ele);
}

$.prototype.html = function(html) {
    this.innerHTML = html;
}

$('test').html('hey');
$('.hey')[0].html('hey');
function cut(string,num) {
    let a = string.slice(0,num);
  let b = string.slice(num + 1,string.length);
  return a + b;
}
```

It doesn't work, the console log reports this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html is not a function
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is what you are returning from the $ function. 
Think about this: document.getElementsByClassName and document.getElementById return dom elements and dom elements don't have a .html function. That is why you are getting the error.

What you need is to return is an object, a wrapper, with a .html function, and a closure over the dom elements that you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're *returning* an object from `$`, you're overriding the default behavior of `new $`; instead of resulting in the newly-created object, it results in the object you returned out of `$`.

Instead, you'd want to remember the results of those `getElementsByClassName`/`getElementById` calls in an array or [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you store on `this` (the newly-created object), and then use that array or Set within `html` (since you want to loop over all matching elements in the case where you're setting the new HTML).

---

Side note: Since you're using ES2015+ features anyway (`let`), you might want to use the simpler [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) syntax instead of a separate `function` declaration and assigning to `$.prototype`:

```
class $ {
    constructor(ele) {
        // ...
    }

    html(html) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: So going off of your class thing, I'm still a little confused on what I would put inside of the html(html) {   }. Would I put this.innerHTML = html? Sorry, I'm still learning a lot.

Comment: @JoeTheHobo - No, as I said above, since you want to loop over all matching elements in the case where you're setting the new HTML, you'd use a loop on the array/Set that you saved in the constructor. When `html` receives an argument (so you're making it a *setter*), you'd set `innerHTML` on the elements in that array/Set, in the loop.

Comment: @JoeTheHobo - Re your deleted answer: No, very much **not** that. :-) Never add to `Object.prototype`. (And if you add to other built-in prototypes, be sure to use `defineProperty` so you're creating a non-enumerable property.) Re Johnny Zabala's answer: No, there's no need to abandon your prototype-based solution (`class` is also prototype-based). While returning an object that closes over the elements is one option, it's not necessary.

Comment: Kay thanks for the help. I just need to look into classes a little bit more to get a better understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my answer don't abandon prototype-based solution. But if you are trying to replicate JQuery you cannot use a `class` base-solution as your main api. If you use a `class` you will need to use the `new` keyword and JQuery don't work like that. You still can have a class underneath and use prototype but if you are mimicking JQuery, a class can't be your api entry point.

Comment: @JohnnyZabala - For some reason I thought the OP had used `new` in the question, but they clearly haven't. My bad. But you refer to returning a closure, which there's no reason to do. (You do need to return an object, but you don't have to create any functions when doing so if, like jQuery, you use a prototypical solution by calling `new` internally.)

Comment: @ T.J.Crowder yeah, you are totally right about that. The closure part is not really necessary. Both approach can solve the problem. Internally you can use the the `class` with `new` or you can have the closure. I just hope @JoeTheHobo has a better idea about how to do it.

Comment: Yes yes, this has really taught me something I never knew before. I've been trying to figure this out for a while so I finally hopped onto this website and asked. You guys answered fast, were really nice and helpful.