# How to add jquery's .html() in vanilla js?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert jquery to lightweight js. But I get error.

Like I want to use jquery's $('#app').html('test');

```
var $ = function (method_name) {
return document.querySelector(method_name);
}

$.prototype.html = function (value) {
this.innerHTML = value;
};

$('#app').html('test'); // <--- .html() is not function
```

How to add .html() in $()?

only $('#app').innerHTML = 'test' is working

Comment: Your function `$` returns an element and not a `$` object.

Comment: So how to convert jquery's $() + $().html() to javascript?

Comment: Take a look at [youmightnotneedjquery.com](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) it has vanilla alternatives for jQuery methods

Comment: You don't need to convert anything... Why would you want to recreate jquery with your own wrapper class? Your `$` function is not even working properly, it would fail for non ID selectors.

Comment: `.prototype` only makes sense if you used `$` with `new`. `$("#app")` is an [`HTMLElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement); these don’t have an `html` method. You could create an instance with `new` inside the `$` function (e.g. by checking [`new.target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)), but this can get complex very quickly. Why not simply use the DOM API directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Jquery's .html() function in Vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032681/how-to-make-jquerys-html-function-in-vanilla-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it with `class`:

```js
class MyJQueryObject {
  constructor(query) {
    this.target = document.querySelector(query);
  }
  
  html(newHTML) {
    if (typeof newHTML !== 'undefined') this.target.innerHTML = newHTML;
    return this.target.innerHTML;
  }
}

const $ = function (query) {
  return new MyJQueryObject(query);
}

const target = $('#target');

console.log(target.html());

target.html('It was easy');
```

```html
<div id="target">Change me if you can</div>
```

Also with `class` you can easily add/remove methods. And the best part that you can define `html` not as function but as property with the help of getters and setters. For me it is more clearly than check if you pass any argument or not. Example of usage:

```js
class MyJQueryObject {
  constructor(query) {
    this.target = document.querySelector(query);
  }
  
  get html() {
    return this.target.innerHTML;
  }
  
  set html(newHTML) {
    this.target.innerHTML = newHTML;
  }
}

const $ = function (query) {
  return new MyJQueryObject(query);
}

const target = $('#target');

console.log(target.html);

target.html = 'It was easy';
```

```html
<div id="target">Change me if you can</div>
```

Comment: jQuery internally does process lists of elements. In order to come somehow close, the above example code should at least be based on `NodeList`s and/or arrays and `querySelectorAll` (and not at all on exclusively `document` and `querySelector`). But then again, why does one want to recreate something which is battle tested for already more than 16 years?

Comment: @PeterSeliger I completely agree with you. But it will more complex if I will start write a full correct code, so I decided to show how it can be achieved and hoped that he can extend this class and methods by himself

Comment: @PeterSeliger And may be didn't like how JQuery methods works and he wants to return the custom values which he need :)

Comment: Thanks, this works but I need to customize some new functions by using prototype. The reason why I want to re-create is because I want faster performance with very lightweight js. I just found alternative jquery js -> CashJS.