# Why is jQuery.html() working when .innerHTML() is failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that produces a `<canvas>` element, that I am attempting to update from jQuery to modern vanilla JS.

Per most documentation on the internet, including [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032681/how-to-make-jquerys-html-function-in-vanilla-javascript) I am attempting to use [`element.innerHTML`](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) to replace jQuery's `html()` method.

However this using `element.innerHTML` fails, whereas jQuery `html()` works:

```
// Fails
// element.innerHTML = qrCodeCanvas.outerHTML;

// Works
$(element).html(qrCodeCanvas);
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikemaccana/0f9t78sz/27/)

How can I replace the `.html()` with vanilla JS?

Comment: What does "fails" mean exactly? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: What's in qrCodeCanvas? Why do you set it as is with html(), but call outerHTML with pure  JavaScript?

Comment: @Teemu no, it's not a string.

Comment: @Pointy No errors are reported - see the JSFiddle mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Teemu it's named qrCodeCanvas because it's literally a `HTMLCanvasElement`, which inherits from `HTMLElement`.

Comment: The jquery equivalent of `element.innerHTML = qrCodeCanvas.outerHTML` is `$(element).html(qrCodeCanvas.outerHTML)` - which *also doesn't work*.   Your codes are not equivalent.

Comment: Stack Overflow has code demonstration capabilities like jsFiddle has, and it's always preferable for code for a question to be **here** and not on an external site.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yep I noticed that too during testing. I know the codes aren't equivalent - that's the nature of the question, if they were the same I wouldn't be asking. What would be the equivalent of `.html()`?

Comment: `<canvas>.outerHTML` doesn't give the you content of the canvas (the actual drawing) because it's not html.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m that comment was the key to understanding what I was doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.html()` function involves a whole lot of work besides updating the DOM via `.innerHTML`.  In this case, you've already got a DOM element (the `<canvas>`) so `.innerHTML` makes no sense. The jQuery code detects that you passed a DOM element (and not HTML text as a string), so it appends it to the DOM for you.

Using `.outerHTML` will turn your `<canvas>` back into a string, but you don't want that because that other code has already *drawn* onto the canvas; getting the HTML will lose that.

The browser API equivalent of `.innerHTML` in this case would be `.appendChild()`.

Comment: Browser APIs are not "vanilla JS", though the population of earth doesn't seem to get that. Question has been updated to include mention of `.appendChild()` to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: It does work: `element.appendChild(qrCodeCanvas);`